# .jsf syntax highlighting file (for joe editor)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, joe

I am trying to modify the .jsf syntax highlighting file for the `joe` editor
`/usr/share/joe/syntax/ini.jsf`. This file contains rules for highlithing/coloring `ini` files. For `ini` files, anything after ";" should be a comment.

```
; comment
key = value ; comment
```

the above works OK, and `joe` colors everything after ";" green. However, id does not work correctly in following case:

```
key = value             ; comment
```

In other words, it only works when there is only one space in front of
the ";". I would like to fix this, but I am struggling with the syntax file structure. Following is a snippet of the relevant part of `/usr/share/joe/syntax/ini.jsf`:

```
:line_start Idle
    *               key             noeat
    "\n"            line_start
    " \t\r"         line_start # leading spaces
    ";#"            line_comment    recolor=-1

:line_comment Comment
    *               line_comment
    "\n"            line_start
```

**Can somebody please suggest how to make the necessary modification?**

Comment: Only the snippet works as expected (You can try.). May be another rule overrides this.

Comment: This section is not the relevant one, since it handles only comments at line start but not after a key-value pair. May I suggest you a look at https://github.com/cmur2/joe-syntax/blob/master/ini.jsf which definetly works (Disclaimer: written by me).

Comment: @cmur2 - thanks for the link. But this is exactly the version of `ini.jsf` which I already have (shipped with joe `3.7-2.3` in Debian Wheezy). And AFAICT, it definitely does not work. (i.e. the coloring works OK with spaces, but not with TABS).

Comment: Ah, okay, yea it's only working with spaces but stackoverflow only shows spaces above. Will fix that at least in my repo.

Comment: @cmur2 - thanks a lot. Actually, I am using `ini.jsf` to colorize `asterisk` config files. They are very similar to `ini` files, but not quite the same (for example, they are using `key = value`, as well as `key => value`). Would you perhaps be interested to create a proper `asterisk.ini` syntax file ?

Comment: Yea why not, can you provide/link a suitable example? Is the default config file featuring all specialities you are interested in?

Comment: that would be fantastic! I have pasted a representative sample config file [here](http://pastebin.com/E7BqBPqG)

Comment: Is it ok for Asterisk to have a semi colon after a section declaration like in "[macro-page];"? Pushed a first version, use it with "joe -syntax asterisk my.conf" after copying it to the right place :)

Comment: that works great! How difficult would it be to add some more advanced coloring of variables `${VAR}` and text inside parenthesis, such as `DIAL(SIP/2222,60)`, or `NoOp(SIP/${EXTEN})`?

Comment: regarding semi colon after a section declaration: I don't think `[macro-page];` is legal. But `[macro-page] ; comment` might be.

Comment: could we make the following comment colorized properly? `[2222](endpoints) ; comment`. At the moment the comment is bright red - same as `(endpoints)`.

Comment: Actually, the same is for `[section] ; comment`.